# Digital transmission sounds

Tags: software-defined-radio, rtl-sdr, digital-voice, lna

I'm playing with an RTL-SDR dongle and an LNA, on Linux Mint with GQRX and DSD
A lot of frequencies show digital transmissions, which the DSD is not converting.  I don't whether it is a format DSD cannot convert, encrypted, or just distorted.

Is there a site were I can listen to how different digital transmission formats (DMR, D-Star, etc.) sound without converting, or any other strange transmissions?

Answer (score 5):

See SigiWiki:

> This wiki is intended to help identify radio signals through example
>   sounds and waterfall images. Most signals are received and recorded
>   using a software defined radio such as the RTL-SDR, Airspy, SDRPlay,
>   HackRF, BladeRF, Funcube Dongle, USRP or others.

https://www.sigidwiki.com/

Answer (score 3):

Here's one from the designer of fldigi.

http://www.w1hkj.com/modes/index.htm